# Das Verb "bekommen" im Perfekt-Satz am Ende

Tags: difference, modal-verb, perfect-tense

Manchmal sehe ein Perfekt + Das Verb bekommen.

- Ich habe das zugeschickt bekommen.
- Mir wurde das geschickt.

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen den beiden Sätzen?
Wird so eine Konstruktion oft gebraucht?

Comment: In Variante 1 ist ziemlich sicher, dass man es schon bekommt hat (wegen des Perfekts), das ist bei Variante 2 nicht garantiert.

Comment: @guidot Stimmt, in Variante 2 ist es zumindest möglich, dass das Versendete noch nicht angekommen ist. In Variante 1 dagegen wird man davon ausgehen, dass es angekommen ist. Das liegt m.E. aber nicht am Perfekt, sondern an der Verwendung von "bekommen" - auch bei "Ich bekam das zugeschickt" würde ich davon ausgehen, dass es angekommen ist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ein offensichtlicher Unterschied ist jedenfalls, dass Sie unterschiedliche Verben (*schicken*/*zuschicken*) verwenden, was bei einer solchen Frage eher suboptimal ist, da Sie so gewissermaßen zwei Variablen verändern. Davon abgesehen:

Die Konstruktion mit *bekommen* ist weit verbreitet; viele sprechen auch von einem eigenständigen *bekommen*-Passiv (in Abgrenzung zum *werden*-Passiv; umstritten). Allerdings sehen viele Sprecher diese Konstruktion als zumindest umgangssprachlich oder stilistisch markiert an (*Eisenberg*, Grundriss der deutschen Grammatik, Bd. 2, 4. Aufl. 2013, S. 127). Das sollte man bei ihrer Verwendung im Hinterkopf behalten.

Im Allgemeinen ist die Bedeutung der *bekommen*-Konstruktion nicht wesentlich anders als die des *werden*-Passivs. Es ist aber dokumentiert, dass in Verbindung mit manchen Verben des Besitzwechsels (auch: *zuschicken*) eine stärkere Betonung des Empfangs bewirkt wird (*Leirbukt*, Untersuchungen zum "bekommen"-Passiv im heutigen Deutsch, 1997, S. 190 ff.). So wird auch in der Literatur beispielsweise die Beobachtung gemacht, dass auf die Beschwerde, eine Ware nicht erhalten zu haben, zwar mit *Wir haben Ihnen die Ware gestern geschickt* geantwortet werden kann, nicht aber mit *Sie haben gestern die Ware geschickt bekommen.* Das gilt allerdings ganz offenbar nur für ganz bestimmte Verben:

> Die endphasenbezogene Darstellung scheint auf solche Verben beschränkt
>   zu sein, die einen "positiven" Besitzwechsel von einiger Dauer
>   bezeichnen: *zustellen, schicken*, Komposita mit *-schicken* und *-senden*
>   (*nachschicken, nachsenden, übersenden, **zuschicken**, zusenden,
>   zurückschicken, zurücksenden*) u.ä. [...] Der Beginn der Transaktion
>   und der aus ihr resultierende Zustand des Besitzens liegen zeitlich
>   etwas auseinander [...] Hinzu kommt u.U. eine lokale Differenzierung.

Es handelt sich mithin um kein allgemeines Merkmal der *bekommen*-Konstruktion.

Answer (score 1):

Ich halte die erste Variante für die normale. Die zweite würde ich am ehesten verwenden, wenn ich meine Ahnungslosigkeit, *von wem* mir das zugeschickt wurde, betonen wollte. Aber grundsätzlich ist beides möglich, der Unterschied ist nicht sehr groß.